# Submit Button Value not being submitted due to Parsley

Tags: parsley.js

I have encountered an issue where the value of a submit button is not being submitted with the form data. This is happening because of parsley. After some more troubleshooting I have discovered that if I make use of the script parsley.js and not parsley.remote.js, the issue is not there anymore.

Note: This issue only happens in Internet Explorer and Firefox, while in Chrome everything works just fine.

### **Working example**

Here is an example in plunkr which demonstrates that with the script - parsley.js, this issue does not happen in neither of the browsers, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ylxasiyrlxhSrhrMaFH?p=preview

This means that if we run the above plunkr in any browser and enter anything in the text box and then click on submit, the submit button value is going to change from "undefined" to "submitBtn" as it should.

### **Not working example**

`Here` is another example in plunkr which demonstrates that with the script - parsley.remote.js, there is this issue in both Firefox and Internet Explorer, while it is fine in Chrome, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/ODqZannjYFBEwppXOXiF?p=preview

This means that if we run the above plunkr in either internet explorer or firefox and enter anything in the text box and then click on submit, the submit button value is never going to change to "submitBtn" as it should, but instead it will always stay "undefined".

Anybody has ever encountered this problem or have a solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering the same issue **under certain circumstances** using the current version of Parsley (2.2.0-rc1) which was *supposed* to fix this (see here: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/947#diff-for-comment-36081575)

It happens for me when 1) I have a form with a parsley-remote validated field, and 2) the remote validator isn't called until I've already clicked the submit button on the form.

Example -- I have a form where a user can change their username, like so:

```
<form id="profile-username" action="/profile" method="post" role="form" data-parsley-validate>
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}" maxlength="255" required
    data-parsley-type="alphanum"
    data-parsley-trigger="change"
    data-parsley-remote="/api/checkuser"
    data-parsley-remote-reverse="true"
    data-parsley-remote-message="Username already taken"
    data-parsley-type-message="Username can only contain letters A-Z and numbers 0-9" >
<input type="password" name="password" required minlength="6" maxlength="150">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Username">
```

If I change the value in the `username` field, it triggers the remote validator.  Later when I click submit, the form will submit including the value of the `input [type=submit]` as expected.

However if I *don't* change the value in the `username` field and just submit the form as is, the remote validator is still called (after I've already clicked submit) but the form posts **without** a value for `submit`, which is not what I want.

It seems to be a timing issue... I'm thinking Parsley is doing things with the submit button behind the scenes which don't have a chance to finish in the time between the user clicking 'submit' and the browser going on to the next page.

**Bottom Line:** In any case it may just be safer to use an `input type="hidden"` to pass whatever value you need, instead of relying on the value of `submit` being there.